# Swift - Returning NSItemProvider from onDrag closure results in error

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop

I am working on a Swift project and encountered an issue with the onDrag closure in SwiftUI. When trying to return an NSItemProvider from the onDrag closure, the compiler raises an error. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```swift
Text(text)
    .onDrag {
        do {
            // Code to encode struct and prepare JSON message...
            return NSItemProvider(object: jsonString as NSString)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return NSItemProvider(object: "" as NSString)
        }
    }
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
Missing return in closure expected to return 'NSItemProvider'
```

It seems that Swift expects a direct return of NSItemProvider, but the do-catch block in the closure complicates the direct return. Is there any way to handle the encoding and return an NSItemProvider properly?

I have tried using [weak sharedState, binding iS, binding jS, binding isInsertS] in the closure's capture list as suggested, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked (ie compiled) as expected. Are you forgetting a case (if/else, guard, etc.) where it doesn't return something?